# SpringBoot+マルチモジュール構成でプロパティファイルからメッセージが取得できない

Tags: java, spring-boot

マルチモジュール構成のSpringBootプロジェクトで
SpringSecurityを使用したログイン画面を作成中です。

ドメイン層側でUsernameNotFoundExceptionが発生した際に
ドメイン層側に置いた
/resources/i18n/messages_ja.propertiesからメッセージを取得したいのですが

No message found under code 'test.error' for locale 'ja_JP'.
が表示され取得できません

■判定処理部分

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MessageSourceImpl message;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (!email.equals("aaaa")) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(message.getMessage("test.error"));
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

/resources配下に置いたmessages.propertiesに記載した際は正しく取得されるので
設定周りだとは思いますが１週間以上試行錯誤してもさっぱりうまくいきません。
どうか手助け頂けると幸いです。本当にどうか宜しくお願い致します。

■ソース全量
https://github.com/hi-soft68/hisohi

初めての投稿で不足がありましたら申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0):

ぱっと見での回答ですが(誤っていたら、すいません)。

`application.yml`は、`hisohi/test-domain/src/main/resources/`には無くてもいいでしょうか？

`application.yml`が無いので、以下の定義が効かなくて日本語メッセージが取得できないのでは、と思いました。

```
spring:
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
```

Comment: ご指摘通り置きましたが改善されませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138494/
こちらに子モジュールにapplication.propertiesを置かないほうが良いと議論されていたので現状は置いてません。

Answer (score 0):

[`--debug` オプション](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output) をつければauto-configure設定などが出力されるので状況が把握しやすくなります。

今回の場合、

- `MessageSource`コンポーネント([`MessageSourceImpl`](https://github.com/hi-soft68/hisohi/blob/master/test-domain/src/main/java/com/example/test/domain/service/MessageSourceImpl.java))を自前で実装したため、 [`MessageSourceAutoConfiguration`は適用されません](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L52)
- (そもそも[自身で `new` している](https://github.com/hi-soft68/hisohi/blob/master/test-domain/src/main/java/com/example/test/domain/service/MessageSourceImpl.java#L14)のでDIは機能しない)

---

自前で [`MessageSource`を構築する](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L66-L85)必要があります。

```
diff --git a/test-domain/src/main/java/com/example/test/domain/service/MessageSourceImpl.java b/test-domain/src/main/java/com/example/test/domain/service/MessageSourceImpl.java
index 35113d6..5f46f48 100644
--- a/test-domain/src/main/java/com/example/test/domain/service/MessageSourceImpl.java
+++ b/test-domain/src/main/java/com/example/test/domain/service/MessageSourceImpl.java
@@ -2,16 +2,28 @@ package com.example.test.domain.service;

 import java.util.Locale;

+import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
+
+import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration;
+import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceProperties;
 import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
 import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable;
 import org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException;
+import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 @Component
 public class MessageSourceImpl implements MessageSource {

-    private MessageSource message = new MessageSourceAutoConfiguration().messageSource();
+    private MessageSource message;
+
+    @PostConstruct
+    public void init() {
+        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
+        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
+        message = messageSource;
+    }

     public String getMessage(String code) {
         return message.getMessage(code, null, Locale.getDefault());
```

`"i18n/messages"` の部分を設定ファイルから読み取りたいのであれば、 [`MessageSourceProperties`相当の実装](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L60-L64)も自前で行うことになります。

---

なお、最新版ではこの辺りの実装が変わっているようですので、挙動も異なるかもしれません。

Comment: 質問への回答ではないのでコメント欄に記載しますが、わざわざ `MessageSource` を implements していることで問題を複雑化させているように思われます。特に意図がないのであれば `MessageSource` インタフェースを使わずに実装することで問題の切り分けも容易になるかと考えます。